# How many functions $f:\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}\to\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ assume exactly 3 distinct values?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, functions

> Suppose the function $f:\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}\to\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\}$ assumes exactly 3 distinct values. If the number of such functions is $N$, find the value of $N$.

I dont know how to solve this question.I only know out of $5$ elements in the codomain we can select the $3$ in $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways. But I don't know how to solve further.Please help.

Comment: Inclusion/Exclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Big hint:** How many functions
$$f:\ \{1,2,3,4,5\}\ \longrightarrow\ \{1,2,3\},$$
are there? How many of them are surjective?

Comment: Why did we count only the surjective functions?@Servaes

Comment: Because you want $f$ to assume *exactly three distinct* values.